# Using Interpreters from the VirtualEnv

Tags: python, virtualenv, autobahn, crossbar

I have started experimenting with Crossbar and WAMP (Web Apps Messaging Protocol) and Im in love with this stuff in just a few weeks time. I answered [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476238/debugging-crossbar-io-app-in-intellij) ([Debugging Crossbar.io app in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476238/debugging-crossbar-io-app-in-intellij)) as well, however, I have a of question about my own solution.

> ...
>
> Step 2: Create a pyenv with Python 2 for crossbar.io
>
> ```
>     $ pyenv virtualenv 2.7.6 crossbar
>     $ pyenv activate crossbar
>     (crossbar)$ pip install crossbar
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Step 5: Create a pyenv with Python 3 for app components
>
> ```
>     $ pyenv virtualenv 3.4.2 app
>     $ pyenv activate app
>     (app)$ pip install autobahn
> ```
>
> Step 6: Create a normal PyCharm project with "app" as a local python environment. I mean use python executable from app pyenv as an
>   interpreter.
>
> ...

In step 5 of my solution, I have suggested to create a new virtual python environment for the app component.

Step 6 is purely for IDE to auto-complete and find the local packages, libraries and stuffs from the virtual env above. I reckon, the "crossbar" command doesn't know about this virtual env.

So, when I run the app by **~/.pyenv/versions/crossbar/bin/crossbar start** command how to make sure to use the python interpreter from the virtual environment instead? I mean from **~/.pyenv/versions/app/bin/python3**?

Is it something to do with the config file?
I quickly had a look at the docs (http://crossbar.io/docs/Container-Configuration/) but unfortunately did not find any information about Python interpreter at all.

I tried to put **"executable": "~/.pyenv/versions/app/bin/python3"** in the config file but it obviously doesn't pass the validation. I mean the **crossbar check** command fails.

Thank you in Advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Python 3 for your *app component*, and have that component started by Crossbar.io, that means you want a *guest worker*.

The way to configure the executable run for the guest worker (which would be Python 3 in your case), is indeed by using the `executable` parameter.

The docs are sparse, but [here](http://crossbar.io/docs/Guest-Configuration/).

Your safest bet is by using a fully qualified, absolute path in `executable` pointing to the Python 3 binary within the virtualenv you want to use for your component.

Note, above applies to *guest workers*. Crossbar.io *native workers* include routers and component container. The latter is also able to host Python app components, but *only* from the same Python that Crossbar.io runs from. The docs (sorry, I know, sparse) is [here](http://crossbar.io/docs/Container-Configuration/).

Comment: Thanks oberstet. I don't mind using twisted at all but, I believe sometimes it is handier to explicitly choose the Python interpreter. Maybe I missed something but I ended up using asyncio based guest workers, however, I need to put the full absolute path in executable. It doesn't bother me too much but is there an easy way to put a relative path instead? So that it becomes easier to version control. Or I can write a bit of script to do it. Anyway thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You can also use relative paths for `executable` (relative to where the `config.json` file resides .. that is, `.crossbar` directory) or you can just use `python3` given that the latter can be resolved in the environment of the Crossbar.io node controller process.